# Netbeans Diff Sidebar - Navigate through changes?

Tags: svn, netbeans, diff

I'm using Subversion for version control. Is is possible to navigate through the diff changes (default blue), added lines (default green) and deleted lines (default red) via shortcut?

So just as you can navigate through document bookmarks, is it possible to navigate/scroll through all changes found by Subversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might have to create your own **Action** as shown in this [tutorial](http://www.packtpub.com/article/netbeans-platform-6-9-working-with-swing-actions).

Comment: Ah okay cheers guys. Well it's been over a year since I properly did any Java but I'll definitely take a look at using actions soon.

Answer (score 1):

In Netbeans 8.2 you can click on the coloured version control bars in the margin and the editor will take you there.

Alternatively, if you right-click on the filename, you can select 'Subversion > Show Changes' (or 'Git' or 'Mercurial', depending on your version control system).

This new window allows you to jump through the changes using the up and down arrows at the top.

I am not aware of any keyboard shortcuts that allow you to jump to the next or previous change.